# Selenium - PhantomJS - socks5. Проблема с загрузкой пустой страницы

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs, socks5

Примерная структура куска кода такова:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
service_args = [
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
        '--ssl-protocol=all',
        '--proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port',
        '--proxy-type=socks5',
        ]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\phantomjs.exe',service_args=service_args)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
try:
      driver.get(link)
      sleep(1)
      host=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='owner-name']").text 
except Exception as e:
            print('Error {}'.format(e))
```

Если я использую socks5, то ловлю NoSuchElementException, а при запросе исходного кода веб-страницы, выдаётся:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Без использования соксов, всё работает, возможно проблема в них, т.к. варианты решения данной проблемы в сети, вроде - использования ignore-ssl в service_args и добавления implicitly_wait не помогают. Смена на более ранние версии PhantomJS(2.0;1.9.8;1.9.6) - не помогает

Comment: предполагаю, что мой ответ здесь - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604512/не-работает-socks5-proxy-в-связке-python3-selenium3-phantomjs2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в socks5, нужны качественные носки(DNS-Forward), также, для phantomjs отлично работают http-proxy, лучше использовать их

```
service_args = [
        '--proxy=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port',
        '--proxy-type=http',
        ]
```